# Entity Framework CTP5 and Ninject as my IOC

Tags: entity-framework, ioc-container, ninject, entity-framework-ctp5

Is it possible in Entity Framework CTP5 to construct retrieved persisted entities via an IOC container?

I'm using Ninject and it's tied in fine with MVC, but I need to inject some services into my domain objects when they are constructed for some business rules.

I'd rather do this using constructor injection than method or property injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what, exactly, you're trying to accomplish here, but EF has almost no extensbility points.  The best you can do is hook into the ObjectMaterialized event fired by ObjectContext.  In CTP5, you need to cast your DbContext like so in the constructor for your DbContext:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += 
    this.ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized;
```

And then implement your function `ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)`.  You will be able to access your object, which unfortunately has already been materialized.  Depending on your needs, you might be able to hack in some interesting behavior here.

BTW, this sentence makes no sense to me:

*I need to inject some repositories into my domain objects when they are constructed for some business rules.*

Doesn't this go against Persistence Ignorant Domain Objects?

Comment: the word repositories should have been services (I've updated my original). For example a domain object may have a few email sending capabilities, so I would like to inject an email service at construction.

Comment: @WDuffy - Makes sense.  Unfortunately, this response (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/c33019e9-2ac4-4cc6-9e0b-3c6557fbf0a6) in the MS forums confirms that because EF requires a zero-arg constructor to materialize your POCOs, you cannot use classic constructor injection.  The only workaround would involve 1) Making this constructor internal, and then 2) Making this constructor call the constructor that HAS arguments that are resolved by your IoC container.  This unfortunately pollutes your POCO with IoC concerns.

Comment: an ICustomerRepository interface is persistence ignorant. If you read the DDD blue book, you'll notice Eric Evans even doing this in a few detailed sequence diagrams. This is the point of repositories, if they truly are repositories and not just fancy data access objects. I personally use Repository interfaces in my aggregate roots and it works out great.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do the inverse of what you are trying to do.  I make my domain objects as ignorant as possible (they are essentially property bags).  When you need to perform some sort of action, like send an email, then I would use a service for that and have the method take in the domain object it needs to perform the action on.  In this case, you would simply need to inject services into various parts of  your application (which is much simpler to accomplish with Ninject).

Comment: Somewhat off-topic:  "property bags" is alarming.  This means that you are in danger of creating an anemic domain.  

Very off-topic:  Cool avatar =)

Comment: I see the benefits to both sides (and to some extent argued both sides).  I do tend to keep simple validation in the objects, so in that sense I guess they aren't strictly property bags, but if an object is complex enough, putting the business logic will quickly bloat the class and it can quickly become over 1,000 lines of code (I've seen it happen a lot).  When I think of the words "business logic" I tend to think of a complex series of rules, if that's the case I prefer a separate class, if it is simply validation, then putting that in the class seems reasonable. Always loved Black Mage!

Comment: +1. I do exactly the same; I keep my POCOs nearly logic-free (save for very simple setter validation here and there.) Concerns like sending e-mail really belong in the service layer. Injecting services into domain objects seems counter-intuitive, IMO.

Comment: I echo the first comment. If your domain objects are property bags, then they're more like domain DTOs, and not domain objects. Google "Anemic Domain Model Anti Pattern". Also, domain services are not intended to be the default location for your domain logic. This defeats the purpose of domain objects encapsulating the business logic.

Comment: You can throw out terms like "anemic data model" and quote people such as Fowler or the likes, but at the end of the day, I've seen far more successful systems written where complex business logic is contained outside of the model then systems where it is all mangled together and hard to maintain. The true value of any system is how well it serves its users, not if it follows various programming principles. I'm not anti-principles, but real world scenarios always outweigh theory as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I understand the pragmatic sentiment, Brian, but then why borrow concepts (DDD) from the people you disparage, and use them not as intended in our projects? You can't have your cake and eat it too. Either go program structurally designed procedural code in your favorite object oriented language, or adopt OOP principles while using domain driven design as its founder intended. It doesn't make sense to mix the paradigms. Furthermore your conception of business value is limited only to immediate user value, and not strategic business value. Systems which avoid anti-patterns are future-resilient.

Comment: And to echo your anecdote about systems being more successful without business logic inside of the model - I agree with your observations. My observation is that our industry isn't quite ready to invest dollars into distilling the core domain. Too many developers apply DDD without having a ubiquitous language, which completely defeats the purpose of DDD. Programming business logic as  transaction scripts is easy to do and read, but not easy to maintain. However, programming business logic in a distilled  model is hard to do, easy to read and maintain. Trade offs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think EF code first CTP 5 can be of some help. It honours IValidatableObject interface, which takes ValidationContext object as an argument. The ValidationContext is a ServiceLocator so you should be able to get the instance of the IoC container using the validationContext object. (This is just my initial thought, I haven't tried anything though). Sorry, if my English is not very understandable.

**Update**
Sorry, just after I posted this comment I realized that the question is quite different than what I understood. So, I did try few things myself, and after some hit and trial and much more googling I was able to get somewhere. I was planning to post the answer here, but then thought against it, since the answer would be very long. So, I did post this blog instead.

http://nripendra-newa.blogspot.com/2011/02/entity-framework-ctp5-injecting-with.html

May be this might help some googlers searching for the same. Hope I got the question right this time.